# Using abstract types with type classes in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I want to use an abstract type `Value` constrained to belong to the type class `Show` from [cats](http://typelevel.org/cats/).

My first attempt would be something like:

```
package examples
import cats._
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._

class UsingShow1 {
  type Value <: Show[Value]  // Not sure if this declaration is right

  def showValues(vs: List[Value]): String = 
    vs.map(implicitly[Show[Value]].show(_)).mkString // Error line

}
```

But the compiler doesn't find the implicit parameter `Show[Value]`.

I know that I can define the previous example as:

```
class UsingShow2[Value: Show] {
  def showValues(vs: List[Value]): String = 
    vs.map(implicitly[Show[Value]].show(_)).mkString
}
```

However, I wanted to know if it is possible to use abstract types instead of type parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add an implicit parameter of type `Show[Value]`, at use site, as usual:

```scala
class UsingShow1 {
  type Value
  def showValues(values: List[Value])(implicit showValue: Show[Value]): String =
    values.map(showValue.show).mkString
}
```

But a more direct translation of your `UsingShow2` class would be the following:

```scala
class UsingShow1 {
  type Value
  implicit def showValue: Show[Value]

  def showValues(values: List[Value]): String =
    values.map(showValue.show).mkString
}
```

Basically, since you’ve traded your type *parameter* `Value` for an *abstract type member*, you also have to trade your implicit *parameter* for an implicit *abstract member* (`showValue` in my example).

Comment: Thanks, the second style is what I was looking for. I wanted to express the constraint on `Show` for `Value` in the abstract type declaration using a single line. Anyway, adding the `implicit def showValue: Show[Value]` is also ok.